# Phonetic Levenshtein Distance

Tags: functions, string-manipulation

I'm working on some code to try to sort the "Fry" sight words (found [here](https://sightwords.com/sight-words/fry/)) into 2 lists sorted by similarity to help my daughter learn to read. I've found that when presented with multiple options, it's too easy for her to just pick the word that begins with the correct letter instead of sounding out the whole word.

So, I'd like to make a version of the list which is sorted by standard Levenshtein distance (with a prioritization on longer word similarities). I'd also like to make a list which is sorted by phonetic similarity.

Mathematica has the ability to scrape the phonetic alphabet data for a given word:

```
groovy = WordData["groovy","PhoneticForm"]
gravy = WordData["gravy","PhoneticForm"]
```

However, it doesn't seem like it can parse the phonetic alphabet as input to the function `EditDistance[]`

The following query gives no calculated output:
`EditDistance[groovy,gravy]`

I'm aware of [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/908930) project, but I feel like this is more complicated than I need, and should be possible in some way using stock Mathematica.

Am I missing a proper way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check FullForm on the variable gravy/groovy. The HEAD is STYLE. Try EditDistance[gravy[[1]], groovy[[1]]]

Comment: Hmm, what version of Mathematica are you using? It appears to work just fine for me in 12.2, giving an edit distance of 2. Fun idea, by the way.

Comment: @OpticsMan your answer works. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlLange I'm on 12.0.0. I'll have to see if my institutional license is updated to the newest version yet. Thanks!

Comment: You might try [`DamerauLevenshteinDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DamerauLevenshteinDistance) instead of [`EditDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EditDistance).